# Error : The term 'bootstrap-vcpkg.bat' is not recognized : While Install C and C++ libraries for Visual Studio 2017 on Win10

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to install C and C++ libraries on my Windows 10 Machine for VS-2017,and encountered the following vcpkg- error. This is the first time I am installing it on my machine.By the way I am using Windows Powershell. I searched online forums alot but not able to figure out whats wrong with my machine or the package installation. Please suggest me how to proceed in this issue

```
    PS C:\Documents\DRAGONFLY\vkpackage\vcpkg-master\vcpkg-master> bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
bootstrap-vcpkg.bat : The term 'bootstrap-vcpkg.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : **ObjectNotFound: (bootstrap-vcpkg.bat:String)** [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: There is a typo somewhere, it should be [bootstrap-vcpkg.bat](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/bootstrap-vcpkg.bat).

Comment: @dxiv, my bad, i was so stressed out of this error that i played a lot with the command and pasted the wrong error message, now the error message is exact. Thanks though.Issue remains the same.

Comment: It's still misspelled on the `+` line. Anyway, what the error says is that the `.bat` does not exist in that directory for whatever reason.

Comment: @SamuelCooper7 If you are definitely sure that the .bat exists in that directory, since you are using powershell, call it like `.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` instead of just `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`

Comment: @SurajS, to be precise , I have cloned the Git Hub project fully and the file is available, somehow i think its Win powershell error not able to recognize it. let me try your way as well...I am following this [doc][1]  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-c-module-windows#prerequisites

Comment: In the link you provided, They specifically ask you to call with a leading `.\\`

Comment: Thanks guys for pitching in and helping me! now i get a better idea of how not to copy paste blindly from portals..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments section, please follow the document : [C modules for Windows devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-c-module-windows#prerequisites) instruction commands one after the other.

```
 git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
        cd vcpkg
        .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
        .\vcpkg install azure-iot-sdk-c:x64-windows
        .\vcpkg --triplet x64-windows integrate install
```

Please mark the response as answered if it is helpful, so that its helpful for other community members.

Comment: Yeah, thank you....i got it now...thanks for the all the comments and answers...

Comment: In Windows the slashes need to be / rather than \, so ./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat and so on. Otherwise the error is 'command not found'

Answer (score 0):

./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat ❌ - it is wrong way

.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat ✅